# Need to filter out all columns which have null,0 or empty values in sql server from a group of tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a bunch of tables about 50 of them and from all of those tables I am trying to figure out a way to filter all the columns which have 0 null or empty values in them. Not sure if sys.tables or Information_schema.tables would have any such function to suffice this.[Like here the last column have null values for all rows so for each table I  supply in my query I need all such column with table name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzkpY.jpg)

Comment: So, you want to discover columns which do not contain useful information in *any* rows?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE table_schema = 'db_name'
  [AND table_name LIKE 'wild']

SHOW TABLES
  FROM db_name
  [LIKE 'wild']
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command will use `NULLIF` two times to deal with `0` and with `''` and with `NULL` all the same. `COUNT()` will not count rows with `NULL`. If the count returns `0`, then there is no other content in this column:

```
SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(NULLIF(CAST(tbl.SomeField AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),''),'0'))
FROM SomeTable AS tbl;
```

The nice part is: You do not have to type this for all columns... The following code will generate this command for all columns of a given table and use `EXEC()` for its execution:

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @tableName NVARCHAR(MAX)='SomeTable'
SELECT @cmd='SELECT '
      + STUFF(
        (
        SELECT ',COUNT(NULLIF(NULLIF(CAST(' +  QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),''''),''0''))'
             + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME('CountOf_' + COLUMN_NAME)
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME=@tableName
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value(N'.',N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
      + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ';'

PRINT @cmd; --check the output in a query window
EXEC(@cmd);
```

You might want to use a `WHERE` clause to reduce this to columns with specific types...

It should be rather easy to take this further to deal with all your tables in a (`CURSOR`) loop dynamically.